# Make two buttons acting as one SwiftUI

Tags: ios, button, swiftui

I want to make two buttons acting as one, or have a single button but with the touch area only the zone that is red like in the picture. A normal button would also have on the touch area that white space on which I put the x-es, which I don't want.

[image]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 0) {
            Spacer()
            
            Button(action: {}) {
                Text("This is button 1")
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 200)
                    .background(Color.red)
            }
            
            Button(action: {}) {
                Text("This is button 2")
                    .frame(height: 100)
                    .background(Color.red)
            }
            
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way it could be done.  Have a single button with two overlaid white rectangles.  Only the red area can be clicked:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 0) {
            Spacer()
            
            Button(action: {}) {
                Text("This is one big button")
                .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                .background(Color.red)
            }
            .overlay(
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    VStack {
                        Rectangle()
                            .frame(width: 100, height: 50)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                        Spacer()
                        Rectangle()
                            .frame(width: 100, height: 50)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                    }
                }
            )
        
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

---

#### Solution using a custom Shape

Another way to do it would be to create a custom `Shape` for the `Button`, and then use it to draw and set its `contentShape()`:

```
struct ButtonShape: Shape {
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Path()
        let width = rect.width
        let height = rect.height
        
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: width/2, y: 0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: width/2, y: height/4))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: width, y: height/4))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: width, y: 3 * height/4))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: width/2, y: 3 * height/4))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: width/2, y: height))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: height))
        path.closeSubpath()
        
        return path
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 0) {
            Spacer()
            
            Button(action: {}) {
                Color.red
                    .clipShape(ButtonShape())
                    .overlay(
                        Text("This is one big button")
                    )
            }
            .contentShape(ButtonShape())
            .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
        
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

This solution overall works better because the clipped areas aren't drawn making it easier to put this button on a colored background for instance.

Comment: I fixed the first solution.

Comment: I have a question/observation for the first solution, it seems that somehow the Rectangles width aren't really 100 points(even though visually they are). On the left margin of the rectangle the button still reacts to touches even if it is covered by the rectangle

Comment: You're right, in the first solution, the touch boundaries are wider on all sides of the button.  In the second case, the touch boundaries are precisely what is drawn.  I can't say why that is.

Comment: it seems also for the second one to be the same problem, anyway, great job, thanks a lot!